# Excel Custom Functions not visible when validated by Microsoft validation team during certification

Tags: office-store, custom-functions-excel

We have developed a add-in for excel with custom functions and the app is hosted on S3 bucket. When we test it from our end on both Excel Desktop and Excel Web (all browsers) we are able to see the custom functions available.
After publishing the add-in to Appsource during process of certification MS team has come back saying that the custom functions are not available once they have upload the add-in.
We are really stuck as we are not able to reproduce the scenario, thus blocking us from providing a fix to the problem.
Please help us if anyone has faced similar issue or redirect us how we can reach out to the team that has done the validation so that we can get additional information.

Comment: Customer Service questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead
https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution